# How to set default bookmarks for Firefox 10 on Mac

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, deployment

I'm trying to create a software image to deploy to Mac laptops. I want the bookmarks to be available when a new user account is created.

From prior versions of Firefox, I tried putting it in:

```
Firefox.app > Contents > MacOS > defaults > profile > bookmarks.html
```

but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated directory was correct. The problem was around the bookmarks.html file. It needs to have read permissions set properly...

It needs to have at least read permission for the staff group.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have clean versions of the bookmarks.html and prefs.js. (If you don't have them, you could probably install Firefox on a clean machine and get them that way.)

Go ahead and set the bookmarks how you want them.

Then you should be able to copy the files from: Firefox\Profiles\default.random into the new \defaults\profile\ folder. You did copy both of the files right? I think you might be missing the prefs.js file..

Comment: I've tried this, but without success. I also tried copying to the \defaults\pref -- also without success. Anything else to look at?

Comment: Found that it was a permission issue on the html file.